# Delete messages sent by telegram bot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

i have a telegram -bot in a group which sends messages like current weather, stock prices , news and so on. at the end of the day i want to clean up the messages sent by bot. however i unable to get the message id of the messages sent by bot using the api 'https://api.telegram.org/botxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxx/getUpdates' and hence i am unable to delete message created by bot.  any updates on this issue will be appreciated

Comment: Do you own that bot which sends the updates ?

Comment: @aditya yes and the bot is also the administrator of the group

Comment: When you send a message you get a response from Telegram that contains the message id. Store them. At the end of the day, iterate over those saved message ids and delete them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should store the message IDs when invoking the send method (from the message object returned) and delete those messages while emptying out your message id storage later on.

This is efficient than your approach for couple of reasons. For instance, with your approach you may have to filter out other messages/updates on that channel that weren't send by the bot (if your bot isn't the only admin who posts content).